# How to convert CSS unicode string to text character?

Tags: html, css, unicode, character-encoding

I'm using an icon set that has to be used through an element like this:

`<i class="icons-recycle"></i>`

This generates an element with the following CSS:

```css
.icons-recycle::before {
    content: "\e67f";
}
```

What I need is to copy/paste the Unicode glyph that's generated via `"\e67f"` so I can use it in Photoshop to do some designs with that icon (I already have the `.ttf` file installed).

For example, `"\u00C6"` gives me `Æ`, according to [this online converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html).

However, I am unable to find what that character is, and I cannot select it on the HTML page! How can I convert this `"\e67f"` to a text character to paste into Photoshop?

MDN says the `content` attribute, when used like this, [is in a Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).

Comment: I found this reference for that code, it looks like it is a kind of Chinese symbol: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e67f/index.htm

Comment: @jtorrescr Awesome, thank you! I needed the character that's in the table next to `string.toUpperCase()`. It's  in this font, but it shows up as the recycle icon with my icons font. Thanks!

Comment: Could it work if you get the svg  from here? You can save it and use it in photoshop https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e67f/sample.svg

Comment: Thanks, I got it. The link you provided the first time around solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Note that U+E67F (as well as all codepoints between U+E000 and U+F7FF) is not a defined character; It's in the private use area, which means a font can display whatever it pleases here.

Comment: @MrLister That's very good info to know, thanks! That explains why in [the link mentioned above](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e67f/index.htm) it's a Chinese character but in my icons font it's the recycle♻️ icon.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found was to use the content string to convert to an [HTML character entity](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp):

Instead of `\e67f`, type `<div>&#xe67f;</div>` (replace the `\` with `&#x`) and the browser will display the individual glyph .

You can then copy/paste into Photoshop, it should display as expected if you have the proper font installed.